# SQL server + group by having with condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, having

I have Customer table (customerid primary key) User table(CustomerId is foreign key, UserID primarykey, AuthStatus column true or false).User table can have N users for same Customer Id. 
I was trying to apply a logic : inner join both table on customerid, but i need to get all customer ids which are having at least one user having a AuthStatus to true.

Is it possible to do this using Group by Customerid,userid but how to apply this logic of at least have one user with AuthStaus as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.customerid
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN User AS u ON c.customerid = u.customerid 
GROUP BY c.customerid
HAVING SUM(u.AuthStatus) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry the actual condition is to check for user's authid = 3 (column in user table),not AuthStatus is true.. I got it to check for condition using case like having sum(CASE WHEN u.authid = 5 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0

Comment: Is there a way to check if at least one user id matches the condition i.e u.authid = 5, the above query groups all the user ids under customer id that meets the condition.